# Gson parsing freezes

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this .json type

```
{"paging":{"page":1,"total":2015,"page_size":20,"pages":101},

"loans":[
    {
    "id":519729,
    "name":"Hefseba Group",
    "description":{"languages":["en"]},
    "status":"fundraising",
    "funded_amount":3125,
    "basket_amount":0,
    "image":{"id":1280581,"template_id":1},
    "activity":"Cafe",
    "sector":"Food",
    "use":"to buy more stock for her cafe, and to buy more fabrics and liquid soap.",
    "location":{"country_code":"TZ",
    "country":"Tanzania",
    "geo":{"level":"country","pairs":"-6 35","type":"point"}},
    "partner_id":87,
    "posted_date":"2013-02-01T09:14:17Z",
    "planned_expiration_date":"2013-03-03T09:14:17Z",
    "loan_amount":4025,
    "borrower_count":16
    },

    {
    "id":520550,"name":"Waridi Pendo Group",
    "description":{"languages":["en"]},
    "status":"fundraising",
    "funded_amount":800,
    "basket_amount":0,
    "image":{"id":1282077,"template_id":1},
    "activity":"Music Discs & Tapes",
    "sector":"Retail",
    "use":"to buy music equipment and DVDs and CDs, as well as to start building his house. ",
    "location":{"country_code":"TZ",
    "country":"Tanzania",
    "geo":{"level":"country","pairs":"-6 35","type":"point"}},
    "partner_id":87,
    "posted_date":"2013-02-01T09:18:11Z",
    "planned_expiration_date":"2013-03-03T09:18:11Z",
    "loan_amount":6100,
    "borrower_count":11
    }
]

}
```

Then I have this code trying to parse it.

```
try{
    JsonReader runThrough = getJsonReader(fileName);
    System.out.println("File found");
    Gson myGson = new Gson();
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray infoArray =  jsonParser.parse(runThrough).getAsJsonArray();
    System.out.println("Finished Parsing");
    for (JsonElement piece : infoArray){

    }
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

I want each loan to be eventually saved into an arraylist of kLoan, but I just have an empty loop for now. The error I get freezes on this line:

```
JsonArray infoArray =  jsonParser.parse(runThrough).getAsJsonArray();
```

Comment: There's a comma at the end of the `loans` list.

Comment: @santiagobasulto - most, if not all JSON parsers ignore superfluous commas.

Comment: I think the missing comma after the planned_expiration_date could be the real problem.

Comment: @schlingel - see my response to your answer

Comment: @rmlan Not all parsers ignore superflous commas. And it'd be bad that it'd happen.

Comment: try adding a comma after "planned_expiration_date":"2013-03-03T09:14:17Z"

Comment: I just copied it wrong, my actual file has the comma. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not a valid JSON file. So maybe that's the reason why the parser get stuck. For details check with JSON lint. There's a comma missing.
2. The overall object isn't a Array. You need to get the property loans and call on this Element the method getAsJsonArray. Like so:

   ```
   try{
       JsonReader runThrough = getJsonReader(fileName);
       System.out.println("File found");
       Gson myGson = new Gson();
       JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
       JsonObject jsonObj =  jsonParser.parse(runThrough).getAsJsonObject();
       JsonArray infoArray = jsonObj.getAsJsonArray("loans");
       System.out.println("Finished Parsing");
       for (JsonElement piece : infoArray){

       }
   } catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println(e);
   }
   ```

Comment: 1 is actually not possible, so I am assuming that this is a typo/omission by the OP. GSON's `JsonParser` would throw a `MalformedJsonException` on an unterminated field. 2, however, is absolutely correct.

Comment: I don't think the comma is the problem. In reference to #2, how do I call on that to then run GetAsJsonArray?

Comment: @user2044299 See my edited answer. It's pretty simple. For further questions see the documentation: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html
By the way: You could also define model classes and let the GSON parser do the extraction work for you.